# Mod_rewrite rules for project in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble with mod_rewrite rules in a PHP site I'm doing.

I'm on Apache 2.4.9 (Unix) - apache that comes with Mac OSX Yosemite.

I have the `.htaccess` file in the root of the project, and it's set up to run in a virtual host... so the address I'm reaching the project from is `http://project.local`. Here's what I have in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Don't rewrite files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Don't rewrite directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^pages pages.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) page.php?var=$1 [QSA]
```

Here's my virtual host set-up:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@me.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Me/Sites/project"
    ServerName project.local
    ServerAlias project.local
    ErrorLog "/Users/Me/Sites/logs/project_error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is what I have in `page.php`:

```
<?php
echo "Hello " . $_GET['var'];
?>
```

I can access `http://project.local/pages` successfully, and it shows the content from `pages.php` from the above rule. But when I go to `http://project.local/page/testpage`, it shows the `Hello` but not the `$_GET['var']`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You _do_ you get when go to `page/testpage`?

Comment: It shows a blank page. If I concatenate a `Hello World` or something, it outputs that on the page, so definitely still reaching the `page.php` page.

Comment: Updated my question with the above example to clarify.

Comment: Try changing your regexp to `^page/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$` (note the `$`). To make sure you match all of the URL.

Comment: @Halcyon `array(0) { }`

Comment: @Halcyon Added the `$` to the end of the regex and still getting same thing. Empty array with `var_dump($_GET)`.

Comment: see php.ini's `variables_order` for the letter `G`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following line to the `.htaccess` file.

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable options `MultiViews` by placing this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# Don't rewrite files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Don't rewrite directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^pages pages.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ page.php?var=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: What hell you entered in browser? Also show your full htaccess in question.

Comment: I access the page with `http://project.local/page/testpage`. I've added an answer for what fixed it. Thanks for the help, I did add `Options -MultiViews`, to `.htaccess` but it doesn't seem to make a difference whether or not it's there.

Comment: The line that you've added should be `Options +FollowSymLinks`

Comment: Now try adding `Options +MultiViews` and then check your $_GET variable.